# How do I collect snow to boil it?

Tags: the-long-dark

I noticed that when I open up a fireplace or stove, there is an option to boil snow (as well as boil water) but I do not know how to collect it.

Is there a bucket or something that I need to find to collect the snow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a tool. All you need to do is select "Boil Snow", adjust the amount to boil, then click "Boil".